# Redis on Bluemix

Tags: java, spring, ibm-cloud, spring-session

We have a Java Spring application running on dedicated bluemix with Tomcat and cloudfoundry. We want to increase the number of running instances, thus we need to replicate our session variables to each instance.

From our perspective the natural path would be using Redis and Spring Sessions.

However, there is big red tag telling us that bluemix Redis support is experimental and should not be used in production environments.

If we can't use Redis in production environments, what is the alternative to session cluster aware in dedicated bluemix?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The two services that are available in Public that you could use are "Session Cache" and "Compose for Redis".

Session Cache: Improve application resiliency by storing session state information across many HTTP requests. Enable persistent HTTP sessions for your application and seamless session recovery in event of an application failure.

Comment: unfortunately those services are not available in dedicated bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Compose Enterprise in Bluemix Dedicated which contains production ready Redis:  https://enterprise.compose.com/

Comment: If you need more info you can connect with me on LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/in/csnowuk/ and send me a message.